# How to fix every link under new added domain?

Tags: domains, sitelinks

I installed smf forum in subfolder on hosted server under my domain. Later on, I occupied new domain, added it to my nameservers and pointed to that folder thru cpanel.

Index works well, link to forum works well, but deeper level links, boards, topics, profiles, login, etc, do not. Not that they don't work per se, but link is not under new domain, and thus user gets loged out when entering site thru new domain address, and gets back to old address once logged in, and similar problems.

What should I do to fix all of the links? I'm guessing that this is because forum is installed before new domain is added on, and links are fixed to old domain. Is there another solution beside backing up and installing everything from scratch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most forum packages (PHPBB, SMF, etc.) have an option to change the domain name inside of the administration panel. I don't have SMF running right now, but I remember seeing something of the sort inside of the admin panel.

You could also simply have a JavaScript redirect page as forum.yourdomain.com that leads to your old domain.

Or, the least savory of all solutions, go into the code and edit the commands yourself. However, since you're using SMF, I'm going to assume that you aren't a PHP savant.

Other than those listed, I don't know of a great solution.

Comment: Yup, can't believe I didn't think of looking in admin panel. Path was set on first domain address there, I changed it and everything works OK.

Thanks plenty :D